# rmpath warning: not found in path

Tags: matlab

In order to temporarily disable a MATLAB toolbox, I was following the instructions from Doug Swartz posted in [this thread](http://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/118774).

The following code should disable and re-enable the symbolic toolbox.

> To disable:
>
> ```
> saved_path = path;
> rmpath([matlabroot '\toolbox\symbolic'])
> ```
>
> To re-enable:
>
> ```
> path(saved_path)
> ```

However, when I run the instruction `rmpath([matlabroot '\toolbox\symbolic'])`, I get the following warning:

> Warning: "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Production
>   Server\R2015a\toolbox\symbolic" not found in path.
>
> In rmpath (line 57)

This is very confusing, because if I display the search path with the `path` command, some of the entries I get are:

```
...
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Production Server\R2015a\toolbox\symbolic\symbolic
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Production Server\R2015a\toolbox\symbolic\symbolicdemos
...
```

Which seems to contradict the warning.

**Why do I get the warning?**

Comment: `C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Production Server\R2015a\toolbox\symbolic` **is not** in path. What's in path is: `C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Production Server\R2015a\toolbox\symbolic\symbolic`. Difference between those two strings is `\symbolic` suffix. MATLAB doesn't do any magic string expansion. It's a list of strings, and your string is not in that list.

Comment: @Rogalski Thanks a lot for your comment. I thought that if a subfolder is in path, then the parent folder has to be too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was assuming that if a nested folder is in path, then the parent folder has to be in path too, but this is not true, as pointed out by Rogalski in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36748104/rmpath-warning-not-found-in-path#comment61077536_36748104).

So there is no contradiction at all, on the contrary, the `path` command is proving the `rmpath` warning by telling that `...\toolbox\symbolic\symbolic` and `...\toolbox\symbolic\symbolicdemos` are in path, but not `...\toolbox\symbolic`.

In order to disable the symbolic toolbox I should disable the two folders one by one like this:

```
rmpath([matlabroot '\toolbox\symbolic\symbolic'])
rmpath([matlabroot '\toolbox\symbolic\symbolicdemos'])
```

I hope that this might help someone facing the same scenario.